# How to create Common log file for multi threaded application in mfc?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

Is there any library file to log the details in the file and check for size limit of the file  and compress the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic search revealed [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)?

Comment: how to implement or use this library in c++

Comment: @karthik follow the link I provided and read the documentation.